# Uninstalling my ubuntu 16.04 dual boot

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot, partitioning

I've seen tons of guides for this, but none seem safe.

I want to replace my ubuntu 16.04 with 14.04. From what I understand, the only way to do this is to uninstall ubuntu and then reinstall it. However, I cannot figure out which disk partitions to uninstall. Here is my windows disk manager:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4hEq.jpg

I allocated 50gb to the Ubuntu install, but there is no combination of partitions there that add up to 50gb. I am worried that some of these partitions might be necessary and that destroying them would brick my computer.

Is it possible for me to just install ubuntu 14.04 on another partition and just write off the 50gb as a loss?

Answer (score 0):

If Windows Disc Manager is to be believed, all the partitions apart from `C:` and `D:` are empty, though I'm not sure I believe it.

If you run the Ubuntu Live CD, you can use `gparted` or `disks` to mount each of the partitions to check their contents with `nautilus` (but you will need to use `gparted` later for partition management). Ubuntu supports a lot more file system types than Windows.

I would leave the first 3 partitions alone (they are normal for a Windows system, and comparatively small) and keep D: (it's the OEM driver and support software installation disc); the final partition is usually the Windows installation files for factory recovery, but if it's empty there's no point in keeping it, unless you plan to reinstate it prior to selling the laptop. If you do delete it, you can now move `D:` to the end of the disc.

I would guess the other partitions are your 16.04 system and swap partitions and these can be safely deleted, unless you need data from the system partition.

Now you should now have at least 45GB for Ubuntu: if you need more, shrink `C:`. I would suggest that you do not define a swap partition during installation, but use a swap file instead, unless you need to hibernate (this needs a swap *partition*). If you need more space, shrink `C:`.

Last and not least, back up everything you need to keep before you make any changes.